# Combine Node.js and Java?

Tags: java, node.js

I want to process *"values"* passed from `node.js` to `java` (perform calculation, write results to DB).

On the server-side I receive information which is entered via node.js-based web application. Since I'm much better with `java`, than I am with `node.js`, I'd like to pass that information to `java` code, and continue processing there.

How can I access values coming from `node.js` in `java` code?
Is there any `node.js <-> java` bridge that I could use?

The goal is to analyse values entered on the webpage. `node.js` application is used for entering and transfering information to server and `java` for further analysis.

Comment: You could use JSON to transfer data between Node.js server and Java server.

Comment: @ErikGillespie: The OP has a node.js-baser webapp, and feels much better implementing data-processing in java. He basically asks for node.js-to-java interop, and there are solutions for this. I belive this question is legit, and would vote against closing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a node.js-based web application, through which you get the data for further processing, but your actual algorithms are written in Java, [node-java](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java) may be a way to go.

[node-java](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java) is a bridge between node.js and java code, and allows you to instantiate java objects, manipulate them and call methods on them.

You can find examples on how to do that on [project page](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java#quick-examples), here's a simple snippet demonstrating what you can do:

```
var java = require("java");

java.classpath.push('path/to/myAwesomeLibrary.jar');
java.classpath.push('target/classes');

java.newInstance("my.awesome.library.DataProcessor", function(err, dataProcessor) {
    dataProcessor.processSomeData("myData");
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do and what I need. Data which I get thorugh node.js for further processing with java!

Now I have to look how it really works! Thanks

Comment: I can't install node-java! I did it as explained on https://github.com/joeferner/node-java#quick-examples , I installed npm install -g node-gyp but I always get the ENOENT error.

Comment: `node-gyp` requires python. Make sure you have `PYTHON` environment variable set and pointing to your python installation.

Comment: python installed and python environment variable set (python 2.7.). Do I have to do additional things?

Comment: Take a look at [`node-gyp` documentation](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation). There's a list of additional software (like Windows SDK, Visual Studio, etc) that you need to install beforehand.